# MSChart not working in other machines

Tags: sharepoint-2010, mschart

I've installed and configured MSChart on my dev server and everything working fine when I access charts from my machine but same don't work when it's accessed from different machines. It throws following error,

```
No http handler was found for request type 'GET' 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: No http handler was found for request type 'GET'
```

I've already updated config file of server's web app with following,

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\Temp\;" />
</appSettings>>

<httpHandlers>
<add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>


<handlers>
<add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solved it?